# Hanging punctuation with \enquote

Tags: punctuation, microtype, csquotes, protrusion

Following [this advice on tex.sx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39285/whats-the-advantage-of-using-csquotes-over-using-an-editors-auto-replacement-f?lq=1), I'm using `csquotes`.

And I'd like to have hanging punctuations, for instance that left-quotation marks are displayed in the margins. I focus on this point in this question.

I did not manage to hangs punctuation in the `\enquote` command. I tried with

- the `hanging` package -- which is by the way not compatible with the `memoir` class, but this is not the subject
- the `microtype` package, that does not seem to hang the quote in my setting.

MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}         % With the minimal class, nothnig is hanged ?
\usepackage{hanging}            % Package to hang the punctuation
\usepackage{csquotes}           % To manage proper quotations
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}                % Quotes in the margin ?
{\hangpunct % The hanging command

``text''                        % Yes

 \enquote{text}                 % No

text            % For reference
}

``text''                        % No

\enquote{text}                  % No

text            % For reference

\end{document}
```

Configuration :

```
pdfTeX, 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 
hanging v1.2b
csquotes v5.1d 
microtype v2.5a
```

Related questions :

- [Microtype and LuaTeX: changing protrusion and hanging punctuation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124129/microtype-and-luatex-changing-protrusion-and-hanging-punctuation)
- [Wrong protrusion with csquotes and microtype](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12852/wrong-protrusion-with-csquotes-and-microtype?rq=1)
- [What's the advantage of using csquotes over using an editor's auto-replacement for "?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39285/whats-the-advantage-of-using-csquotes-over-using-an-editors-auto-replacement-f?lq=1)

I saw on two blogs ( http://blog.tasuki.org/hanging-punctuation/ and http://visuel.ouvaton.org/Vmicrot.htm) that there was a possible way with `\pdfprotrudechars=1`, but I simply couldn't make it work.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don’t worry, this is normal — the first line of an indented paragraph are not outdented.

Minimum working example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}        % For convinience, show the margins
\geometry{a5paper,showframe} % Use a5 size paper and display a border around the
                             % edge for debugging purposes
\usepackage{csquotes}        % Defines \enquote
\usepackage{microtype}       % For hanging indents (no config needed)
\begin{document}

\textit{A regular indented paragraph has no hanging punctuation applied until
the second line}:

``text'' ``text'' ``text'' ``text'' ``text'' ``text'' ``text'' ``text''
``text'' ``text'' ``text'' ``text'' ``text'' ``text'' ``text'' ``text'' ``text''
``text'' ``text''

\vspace{1em}\hrule\vspace{1em}

\textit{The same applies to paragraphs consisting of \texttt{\char`\\ enquote}
commands}:

\enquote{text} \enquote{text} \enquote{text} \enquote{text} \enquote{text}
\enquote{text} \enquote{text} \enquote{text} \enquote{text} \enquote{text}
\enquote{text} \enquote{text} \enquote{text} \enquote{text} \enquote{text}
\enquote{text} \enquote{text} \enquote{text} \enquote{text}

\vspace{1em}\hrule\vspace{1em}

\textit{However, paragraphs with no indent use hanging punctuation on the first
line}:

\noindent
\enquote{text} \enquote{text} \enquote{text} \enquote{text} \enquote{text}
\enquote{text} \enquote{text} \enquote{text} \enquote{text} \enquote{text}
\enquote{text} \enquote{text} \enquote{text} \enquote{text} \enquote{text}
\enquote{text} \enquote{text} \enquote{text} \enquote{text}
\end{document}
```

[image: A sample of quotations hanged]

If you want the punctuation to be entirely in the margin, raise the value of the "factor" value in microtype, by letting :

```
\usepackage[factor=2000]{microtype}
```

[image: Second sample, the quotes are clearly in the margin]

More on what the value of `factor` corresponds to (from [the Microtype Package Documentation, p. 7, sec. 3.2 — Character protrusion](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/microtype/microtype.pdf)):

> Using this option, you can globally increase or decrease the amount by which the
>   characters will be protruded. While a value of 1000 means that the full
>   protrusion as specified in the configuration (see section 5.1) will be used, a
>   value of 500 would result in halving all protrusion factors of the
>   configuration. This might be useful if you are generally satisfied with the
>   settings but prefer the margin kerning to be less or more visible (e.g., if you
>   are so proud of being able to use this feature that you want everybody to see
>   it, or – to mention a motivation more in compliance with typographical
>   correctness – if you are using a large font that calls for more modest
>   protrusion).

Comment: I'm confused. Is this post an answer to your problem?

Comment: The question was not correct : a quote symbol occuring at the beginning of an indented paragraph should *not* be displayed in the margin (of course !). The enquote environment can handel hanging punctuation, and the hanging package is in this setting useless. So to me, yes, this is an answer. Sorry if it is not clear.

Comment: @9999years I would upvote your edition if I could!